# (Delphi) How to read a string variable and split it into multiple lines and put into a listbox

Tags: string, delphi, variables

I have a string containing the following multi-line string value that I read from my database:

```
01/01/2000, 8:00
02/07/2001, 8:00
09/12/2002, 23:00
```

How can I put each of those lines into a listbox on its own line.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the unecessary details. Not only does it make the question make more sense, other people who come along later might find your question useful. And then you might get UPVOTES instead of downvotes.

Comment: @WarrenP, The issue was in fact `RecordSet.GetString`. please read comments on answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a list box at hand, and the database hands you a string with line breaks embedded, then you can simply do this.

```
ListBox.Items.Text := QueryString;
```

When you assign to the [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.Text) property of `Items`, the string will be parsed by splitting on line breaks. Each line is added to the list box as a separate item.

If your string is using a different delimiter, then you can use [`DelimitedText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.DelimitedText) and [`Delimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.Delimiter) instead.

Comment: Just adds them all as one big long string :S

Comment: In the question, you indicated that the string contained line feed delimiters. But your comment shows that not to be the case. How are the lines delimited?

Comment: I'm using ShowMessage(QueryString) to display the message for and its returning the above :S but in the list box it returns long long line :S sorry, fairly new to everything, doing school coursework, but thanks!

Comment: @JamesB123 change your `RowDelimiter` to `#13#10` instead of an empty string (`''`) and David's code will work.

Comment: @kobik I can't see `RowDelimiter` anywhere. My reading of the docs is that `Text` splits on newlines.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it's the parameter used by [`RecordSet.GetString`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/quickref/recordset_getstring.html). default is set to CR. that is why you see the line breaks in `ShowMessage` but it's not breaking with `TSrings`.

Comment: @kobik Thanks. I know nothing at all about data bases!

Comment: I actually do know a bit about databases, but `RowDelimiter` is news to me too. Thanks @kobik